# How to make tableViewCell not receive the slide event?

Tags: ios, events, uitableview, slide, editing

I want a superView respond to the slide event, but seems tableViewCell will catch this event first and make the cell enter the editing mode. Anyone has a solution?

I use a UITableViewController as a childViewController, I want the parentViewController to respond to the slide event.

Comment: Which is your self.view?

Comment: is the cell user editable?

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want the table view cell to respond to the swipe at all then add a swipe gesture to the view.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer * guesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget: action:@selector()];
```

then add it to your view.

```
[self.view addGestureRecogniser:guesture];
[guesture release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Override tableView delegate method

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return  ([tableView isEditing]) ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a transparent UIButton to the UITableViewCell before and it catches the touch event before the UITableViewCell receives the touch event, so it might work for swipes as well. Just add the UISwipeGesture to the button subview to call your method.